# Need help identifying these sets

Tags: set-identification

I recently got a huge bag of LEGO's.  I figured out what some of them were, but there were still these left over, and I couldn't find anything about them.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parts on the left of the top photo are from
[76020-1: Knowhere Escape Mission](https://brickset.com/sets/76020-1/Knowhere-Escape-Mission)
[image]

the part on the right of the top photo is
[30156pb02 : Panel 4 x 6 x 6 Sloped with Stone Wall Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30156pb02#T=C)

based on the windows it should come from [7785-1: Arkham Asylum](https://brickset.com/sets/7785-1/Arkham-Asylum)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The bottom one is part of [6873-1: Spider-Man's Doc Ock Ambush](https://brickset.com/sets/6873-1/Spider-Man-s-Doc-Ock-Ambush)

[image]

You can see the distinctive riser on the left.

Comment: What do you mean by Riser?